# как можно сделать проверку через цикл?

Tags: c++

- Двухмерный массив из 3 строк и 3 столбцов заполнить 0 и 1, это будет результат игры в крестики-нолики.
- Вывести «да», если игра закончилась победой крестиков.
  можно конечно сделать 8 проверок через if else, но можно ли сделать это как то через цикл?

```
   void main()
   {
       using namespace std;
       const int a = 3;
       const int b = 3;
       int an[a][b];
       for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
           {
               an[i][j] = rand() % 2;
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
           {
               cout<< an[i][j];
           }
           cout<< endl;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Два варианта решения через цикл. Вариант простой - циклом 3*3 обойти по три вертикали и три горизонтали (вертикаль и горизонталь можно в один цикл), а диагонали - отдельным циклом на 3.

Comment: Вариант 2 - создать массив координат 3 пары координат * 8 случаев  = 48 елементов в массиве - и цикл на 8 случаяев - проверки (внутри которого 3 проверки пар, можно как с циклом так и без).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, X, N;
    bool fl = true;
    for (int i = 0; fl && i < n; i++) // в этом цикле проверка по строкам
    {
        X = 0, N = 0;
        for (int j = 0; fl && j < n; j++) {
            if (x[i][j] == 2)
                X++; // если в строке встретился нолик то переменную X увеличиваем на 1
            if (x[i][j] == 1)
                N++; //если в строке встретился крестик то переменную N увеличиваем на 1
        }
        if (X == 2 && N == 0) // если в строке два нолика и нет крестиков (т.е. мы рассматриваем не только два рядом стоящих нолика, но и через одну свободную клетку)
        {
            fl = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (x[i][j] == 0)
                    x[i][j] = 2; // то вычисляем, где свободная клетка и ставим туда нолик
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; fl && i < n; i++) //в этом цикле аналогичная проверка по столбцам
    {
        X = 0, N = 0;
        for (int j = 0; fl && j < n; j++) {
            if (x[j][i] == 2)
                X++;
            if (x[j][i] == 1)
                N++;
        }
        if (X == 2 && N == 0) {
            fl = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (x[j][i] == 0)
                    x[j][i] = 2;
        }
    }
    X = 0, N = 0;
    for (i = 0; fl && i < n; i++) // здесь идет похожая проверка по главной диагонали
    {
        if (x[i][i] == 2)
            X++;
        if (x[i][i] == 1)
            N++;
    }
    if (X == 2 && N == 0) {
        fl = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (x[i][i] == 0)
                x[i][i] = 2;
    }
    X = 0, N = 0;
    for (i = 0; fl && i < n; i++) // здесь идет похожая проверка по побочной диагонали
    {
        if (x[2 - i][i] == 2)
            X++;
        if (x[2 - i][i] == 1)
            N++;
    }
    if (X == 2 && N == 0) {
        fl = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (x[2 - i][i] == 0)
                x[2 - i][i] = 2;
    }
    //
    for (i = 0; fl && i < n; i++) //если вышеперечисленных вариантов нет, то ищем нолик с пустой рядом клеткой и ставим туда нолик
        for (int j = 0; fl && j < n; j++)
            if (x[i][j] == 2) {
                if (i > 0 && x[i - 1][j] == 0) // здесь проверка верхней клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i - 1][j] = 2;
                }
                else if (j > 0 && x[i][j - 1] == 0) // здесь проверка левой клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i][j - 1] = 2;
                }
                else if (i < 2 && x[i + 1][j] == 0) // здесь проверка нижней клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i + 1][j] = 2;
                }
                else if (j < 2 && x[i][j + 1] == 0) // здесь проверка правой клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i][j + 1] = 2;
                }
                else if (i > 0 && j > 0 && x[i - 1][j - 1] == 0) // здесь проверка левой верхней клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i - 1][j - 1] = 2;
                }
                else if (i > 0 && j < 2 && x[i - 1][j + 1] == 0) // здесь проверка правой верхней клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i - 1][j + 1] = 2;
                }
                else if (i < 2 && j < 2 && x[i + 1][j + 1] == 0) // здесь проверка нижней правой клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i + 1][j + 1] = 2;
                }
                else if (i < 2 && j > 0 && x[i + 1][j - 1] == 0) // здесь проверка нижней левой клетки на то что она свободна и если она свободна то ставим туда нолик
                {
                    fl = false;
                    x[i + 1][j - 1] = 2;
                }
            }
    if (fl) // если нет и такого варианта, то выбираем место очередному нолику с помощью rand()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    }
```